Is there a planar connected graph with degree sequence $\{ 5,5,5,3,3,3 \}$?
I am looking for a planar, connected graph with six vertices that has degree sequence $\{ 5,5,5,3,3,3 \}$. I think it is impossible to draw such a graph, since these three vertices with degree five need 15 edges, but the graph itself has 12 edges. Of course these degree five vertices can be adjacent, however the planarity corrupts in that case too (I think)! I need a logical explanation.

It has a $ K_{3,3} $ as a subgraph so the answer is no by a famous theorem of Kuratowski.

"but the graph itself has 12 edges" where did you get that? And the degree five vertices are adjacent as there are only six vertices, those vertices basically have to be adjacent to every other vertex.

Kuratowski theorem here

Funnily, this question  deals with a very similar sequence of degrees but for a simplicity issue instead of a planarity issue.
